# If $u_{n+1}= u_n + a_ne^{-u_n}$ with $u_0>0$ and $a_n>0$, then the sequence $(u_n)$ converges if and only if the series $\sum a_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a positive sequence and $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such as :
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        u_0 \in \mathbb{R}_+ \\
        u_{n+1}= u_n + a_ne^{-u_n}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

Show the equivalence between :

- (1) - The sequence $(u_n)$ is convergent
- (2) - The series $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

**What I did :**

- $(u_n)$ is increasing (because : $u_{n+1} - u_n = a_ne^{-u_n} \geq 0$ )

Comment: Surely you can do more than that? At least, the fact that (2) implies (1) should be clear, starting from your remark...

Comment: The inverse implication shold be clear too by the same inequalities but on the other hand.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't really know... If the series $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n$ is convergent, then $a_n \rightarrow 0$ so $u_{n+1} - u_n \rightarrow 0$ but does that implies that $u_n)$ is convergent?

Comment: A monotonic sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent if and only if it is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(u_n)$ is increasing and non-negative.

Suppose $\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n = l$. The series $\sum_{n}(u_{n+1}-u_n)$ is convergent (its sum is $l-u_0$), which implies $\sum_{n}(a_ne^{-u_n})$ converges. Note that $a_ne^{-u_n} \sim a_ne^{-l}$, and since these are non-negative numbers, this implies convergence of $\sum_{n}(a_ne^{-l})$, hence convergence of $\sum_{n}a_n$.

Suppose $\sum_{n}a_n$ converges. Since $(u_n)$ increases, it has a limit in $[0,\infty]$. If this limit is finite, we're done. If $\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n=\infty$, $a_ne^{-u_n}=o(a_n)$. Since these are non-negative numbers, we get convergence of $\sum_n a_ne^{-u_n}$, that is to say convergence of $\sum_{n}(u_{n+1}-u_n)$. Let $l=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(u_{n+1}-u_n)$. Then $u_n$ converges $l+u_0$, a finite value, hence a contradiction.